QField error codes
What does the error code 19 mean in QField (QField 3.2.2 - Congo)?
The error occurs when trying to import a project from ZIP. After selecting the ZIP it first messages that it is importing the project, but the project folder does not show up in the "imported projects" section. The QField message log gives me "error code 19".
I maybe need to add, that importing the specific project from ZIP has worked in the past.
